# How to create an empty file on gulp task?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Currently I use browserify and I don't need `vendor.bundle.js` any more which was generated by webpack 4 `optimization.splitChunks` feature.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendor.bundle.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/search.bundle.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

However I want to keep `vendor.bundle.js` reference for future use.

So I want to generate empty file `dist/vendor.bundle.js` in gulp task.

And... how to?